# Should I reach out to PI regarding my application after having submitted it?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science

I reached out to a potential PI because we had good research fit back in November. The PI also replied to my mail and told I have good research fit with his lab and told me to apply to the program. I applied in December but haven't heard anything so far from him and did not receive any interview invite as well. Is it okay to reach out to him or I should back down and just see how the decision goes at this point?

location: USA
field of study: Computer Science
Program: PhD

Comment: It's a good idea to contact the PI and let him know that you applied to his university and are awaiting the results. No harm in doing this.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, acceptance or rejection will come from the admissions committee, not the PI (almost everywhere). You could ask the PI whether he has any information to share, but he may not. It is likely that he isn't involved in the decision at all.

You might also be able to ask the committee when you might know more.

Unlike other places it is typical in the US to choose an advisor only after you are admitted. There are a few exceptions, and fewer in CS, I think.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Not directly related to the question, but is not getting an interview a bad sign at the moment. Is it common to receive admits without interview?

Comment: Interviews aren't always required so it is hard to judge. It seems a bit early yet for offers, but not too much longer.